# Keep getting uninitialized constant ProfileController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Keep getting this error when I try to go to the link for a new profile. Each user has only one profile and profile belongs to user. Can't find any solutions online. Seems like all my files and code is written properly. Here's my code:

home.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Create your profile!", new_user_profile_path(user_id: current_user.id) if user_signed_in? %>
```

profiles/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class=" mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
        <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Create your profile</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path do |f| %>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield field">
            <p>First name</p>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', placeholder: 'Elon' %>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield field">
            <p>Last name</p>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', placeholder: 'Musk' %>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield field">
            <p>Contact Email</p>
            <%= f.email_field :contact_email, autofocus: true, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', placeholder: 'elonmusk@boringcompany.com' %>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield field">
            <p>Description</p>
            <%= f.text_area :description, autofocus: true, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', placeholder: 'I like self-driving cars, rocket ships, and solar energy! Oh and boring tunnels.' %>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border actions">
            <%= f.submit "Update Profile", class: 'signupform mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent' %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
            </div>
      <div class=" mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
    </div>
```

profiles/new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :profile

end
```

profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  # GET to /users/:user_id/profile/new
  def new
    # Render blank profile details form
    @profile = Profile.new
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users do
    resources :profile
  end
```

Comment: Did you realize the error says `Profile` controller, yours is called `Profiles`?

Answer (score 0):

Controller name is plural, so your routes should like this

```
 resources :users do
    resources :profiles
  end
```

note: `profiles`, not `profile`